# this.props returns undefined error when setting attributes for a component by importing it into another component

Tags: reactjs

I have two Components which counter and counter in which i have imported counter in counters component and added some attributes for counter component.

when i tried to modify the counter value in state object of counter component it shows the error as cannot read the value of undefined.

```js
// Counters Component:

import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [{
        id: 1,
        value: 4
      }, {
        id: 2,
        value: 0
      }, {
        id: 3,
        value: 0
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        value: 0
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return ({
      this.state.counters.map(counter => ())
    });
  }
}

Counter Component::
  state = {
    value: this.props.value,
    -- - > here this.props returns undefined.
    tags: []
  };

render() {
  `enter code here`
  console.log("props", this.props);
  -- -- > here props was printing in console.
}
```

Comment: post full code please. I dont understand when looking to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing :

```
state = {
    value: this.props.value,
    -- - > here this.props returns undefined.
    tags: []
  };
```

Try this:

```
constructor(props){
 this.state={
   value:props.value,
  }
}
```

Comment: why is that ?? @DJ Yadav

Comment: @KiranTirumalasetty Read more about this here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes